# PHP script processing data makes cpanel run out of phyiscal memory (Solutions/alternatives?)

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a php script that has to process txt files (from an external source), there are multiple files but together they add up to over 3 million lines that I have to process.

I do this with the generator functions, I have a function Read():

```
function Read($url)
{
    $handle = fopen($url, "r");

    while(!feof($handle))
    {
        yield trim(fgets($handle));
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Then I iterate over it with foreach. This goes well to a certain point untill my cpanel runs out of phyiscal memory. I tried putting it in a cronjob (which is the purpose of this script really...) but the cronjob doesn't seem to run (probably runs out of memory aswell) and doesn't even give error messages.

Are there ways to solve this or is the only way to upgrade my webhost so I have more physical memory to work with?

Comment: Do you have to have all three million lines in memory in order to process it? If you can break it into chunks, or process each line as you read it (and then discard its data from memory), you'll only use as much RAM as one chunk/line needs.

Comment: Do you have ssh access? If so, you should be able to test your cron-job from the command line and get its output.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't need all lines in memory, I Insert/update them to in a database. How would I discard the lines from memory once they have been processed?